# Fix Gradle (installing libGDX) error? "Invalid project description"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to use Gradle to install libGDX but there's an annoying error I can't fix:
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please include the contents of your build.gradle files in your question. Also, it's more helpful to include the text of error messages in your question rather than a screenshot, particularly if you don't have sufficient reputation to actually include the screenshot in your question.

Comment: Had the same issue - for Eclipse you can't have the project dir to be a workspace dir. Please check if it applies to your issue? It worked for me - got the same error message disappeared.